# GMAIL API Pub/Sub why a new thread is created each time the callback function is called?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

Hello I am currently experiencing problems with GMAIL API. I use the Pub/Sub methods given by the API but each time that the callback function is called (when a new INBOX comes in) it creates a new thread resulting in a lot of CPU consumption after few hours. A sample of my code is below :

```
subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
topic = "myTopic"
subscription_name = "mySub"
subscription = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name)

def callback(message):
    print("Let's GO !!")
    mp.get_messages_of_interest()
    message.ack()

future = subscription.open(callback)
# block the main thread
future.result()
```

EDIT : The problem of new thread appearing has nothing to deal with `mp.get_message_of_interest` since commenting it results in the same issue.

Comment: what's your expected outcome?

Comment: I just want to avoid Sleeping threads which accumulates through time while my script is running. My function `mp.get_messages_of_interest()` just parses the mailbox and do some stuff according to the sender. It parses the emails and extract informations. Then these are sent to an external API using a POST method.

Comment: Is this the issue you're seeing?  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/4563

Comment: Yes it looks like !

Comment: Any idea on how I can fix this ?